# Swift optional chaining with non-nil value

Tags: swift

I have the following program which works fine -

```
class Person {
    var pet: Pet?
}

class Pet {
    var name: String

    var favoriteToy: Toy?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Toy {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let q = Person()
// Pet(name:"goofy")
// Toy(name:"teddy")

if let someToy = q.pet?.favoriteToy?.name {
    print("This person's pet likes \(someToy).")
} else {
    print("This person's pet does not have a favorite toy")
}
```

Prints:

> This person's pet does not have a favorite toy

How to use the above code modified to print "This person's pet likes teddy."?

I know I will have not be able to use `if let` as there will be nothing to unwrap. So I have to write something like this instead of `if let`:

```
let someToy = q.pet.favoriteToy.name
print("This person's pet likes \(someToy).")
```

Should print "This person's pet likes the teddy."

I also know I have to put non-nil value something like this:

```
class Person {
    var pet = Pet ()
}
```

Still I am having initialization problems. How to go about it?

Comment: Your code prints `This person's pet does not have a favorite toy` because `q` does not have a pet set so it is `nil`. Assign it a pet. And assign the per a toy.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your immediate needs...

```
let man = Person()
let goofy = Pet(name: "goofy")
let squeaky = Toy(name: "squeaky toy")

goofy.favoriteToy = squeaky
man.pet = goofy
```

But if a person is usually going to be initialized with a pet and a toy, and both of those classes are initialized with a string, then you might want to define a convenience initializer:

```
class Pet {
  var name: String
  var favoriteToy: Toy?
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

class Toy {
  var name: String
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

class Person {
  var pet: Pet?
  convenience init(petName: String, toyName: String) {
    self.init()
    let toy = Toy(name: toyName)
    let pet = Pet(name: petName)
    pet.favoriteToy = toy
    self.pet = pet
  }
}

func test() {
  let bill = Person(petName: "goofy", toyName: "squeaky ball")
  guard let toyName = bill.pet?.favoriteToy?.name else { return }
  print(toyName)
}

test()
```

One more thing: [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) can be combined with a [guard statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) to great effect in Swift.

Comment: Your first answer (immediate needs...) works as follows:-                    let someToy = man.pet!.favoriteToy!.name
     print("This person's pet likes \(someToy).")
prints - This person's pet likes squeaky toy.                                  Though, I could not make your second answer (convenience initializer) work,it shows error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo inside the Person init.

Comment: Thanks, but how to make toy name nil in both of the above cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `? = nil` in your initializer to pass in some optional parameters.

```
class Person {
    var pet: Pet?

    init(pet: Pet? = nil) {
        self.pet = pet
    }
}

class Pet {
    var name: String

    var favoriteToy: Toy?

    init(name: String, toy: Toy? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.favoriteToy = toy
    }
}

class Toy {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let q = Person(pet: Pet(name: "goofy", toy: Toy(name: "teddy")))
// Pet(name:"goofy")
// Toy(name:"teddy")

if let someToy = q.pet?.favoriteToy?.name {
    print("This person's pet likes \(someToy).")
} else {
    print("This person's pet does not have a favorite toy")
}
```